# Best practice for at-least-once with using EventProcessorHost for Azure Event Hubs?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am experimenting with how [EventProcessorHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessorhost?view=azure-dotnet) handles exceptions. For this, I am using the following sample apps:

- [SampleSender](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/SampleSender)
- [SampleEphReceiver](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/SampleEphReceiver)

What I am observing is, for example, in [this function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/12b87e6038bd18667b9a064e259c7e0b2f7c5839/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/SampleEphReceiver/SimpleEventProcessor.cs#L33), if you receive 15 messages:

Message 0, Message 1, Message 2, .., Message 14

and an exception is thrown without processing them. Next time when you restart SampleEphReceiver, there are cases where those 15 messages are not picked up by `ProcessEventsAsync`. How would you implement an event processor class so that it never loses a message?